# JavaScript reduce methods

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, reduce

I want to convert an array of objects in to object with one of the properties as a key

how to convert the array

```
const data = [
  {
    id: "first",
    name: "Product 1",
    type: "selection"
  },
  {
    id: "second",
    name: "Product 2",
    type: "text"
  },
  {
    id: "third",
    name: "Product 3",
    type: "csv"
  }
]
```

like this

```
{
  first: { name: 'Product 1', type: 'selection' },
  second: { name: 'Product 2', type: 'text' },
  third: {name: 'Product 3', type: 'csv' },

}
```

using ARRAY.REDUCE METHOD?

Comment: `var newData={};
for(let i=0;i<data.length;i++)
{
  newData[data[i].id] = data[i];
}
console.log(newData);`

Comment: This is going to create the new object where you get the desired data.

Answer (score 2):

try

```js
const data = [
  {
    id: "first",
    name: "Product 1",
    type: "selection"
  },
  {
    id: "second",
    name: "Product 2",
    type: "text"
  },
  {
    id: "third",
    name: "Product 3",
    type: "csv"
  }
] 
const obj = Object.fromEntries(data.map(item => [item.id, item]));

console.log(obj);
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this

```js
const data = [
  {
    id: "first",
    name: "Product 1",
    type: "selection"
  },
  {
    id: "second",
    name: "Product 2",
    type: "text"
  },
  {
    id: "third",
    name: "Product 3",
    type: "csv"
  }
]

const result = {};
data.forEach(d=>{
   result[d.id] = {
   name: d.name,
    type:d.type
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to do using [Array.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce):

```js
const data = [
  {
    id: "first",
    name: "Product 1",
    type: "selection"
  },
  {
    id: "second",
    name: "Product 2",
    type: "text"
  },
  {
    id: "third",
    name: "Product 3",
    type: "csv"
  }
];

const result = data.reduce((acc, obj) => {
  const { id, ...rest } = obj;
  acc[id] = rest;
  return acc;
}, {});

console.log(result);
```